# postgresql: how to add timestamp and primary id to this random table SQL

Tags: postgresql

I have the following random table data sql

```
create table foo as select random() as col1, 
                            left(md5(i::text), 10) as col2,
                            md5(random()::text) as col3,
                            left(md5(random()::text), 4) as col4,
from generate_series(1,10) s(i)
```

It creates 10 rows of data.

But now I want to add `col5 (timestamp)` <-- just like creation time (its auto inserted) when the row is added

and also a `col0 - primary unique key`

Comment: Use `col5(now())`?

Comment: how to add primary unique key col0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
select
    row_number() OVER () AS row,
    now() as col5,
    ...
```

Comment: thank you. for me `now() as col5` worked instead of `col5(now())`. Also how to mention `row_number() OVER ()` as primary key

Comment: `row_number() OVER () AS row` will output row|1, row|2 etc. But maybe this is not what you want?

Comment: i want that only